# I have written the following program for XORing 2 cipher texts in hexadecimal using java. How do i convert output to ASCII

Tags: java, hex, xor

I have written the following program for XORing 2 cipher texts in hexadecimal using java. but the output is not correct. Also how do I convert the output in ASCII?

```
public class JavaApplication1 {          
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String y="a12104c6134e57914f104f2521ba4422c4d7b184f4815541f80484e1e24161d64d54ba2210194510164d4f3a0534304e43e1e1da524612171b11701be45431cc1d16a52d11744e1961a114de55174f84e54371";
    String z="32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee11d945cd7fc81a05e9f85aac650e9052ba6a8cd8257bf14d13e6f0a803b54fde9e77472dbff89d71b57bddef121336cb85ccb8f3315f4b52e301d16e9f52f904";
    String d;    
    String s="a";    
    char strfory[] = new char[2];   
    char strforz[] = new char[2];   
    String stry,strz;   
    for(int i=0; i<y.length();i+=2)    
    {
        strfory[0]=y.charAt(i);
        strfory[1]=y.charAt(i+1);
        strforz[0]=z.charAt(i);
        strforz[1]=z.charAt(i+1);
        stry = new String(strfory);
        strz = new String(strforz);
        int a=Integer.parseInt(stry,16);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(strz,16);
        int c=a^b;
        d=Integer.toHexString(c);
        s=s.concat(d);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell what you want to achieve. You didn't tell what is wrong with the output. You didn't tell what XOR encryption you are using. "What's wrong with the code?" is not a question for SO!

Comment: @AbdulFatir I have mentioned that in the title itself.I want to xor 2 cipher texts in hexadecimal using java. i have written the above code to do that. i want to convert the output to ascii so how do i do that?

Comment: Edit the question and add a sample output you want so that I may look into the problem. There are many types of XOR encryption so you need to explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `java.math.BigInteger`:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Example {

    private static final int VALUES_RADIX = 16;
    private static final String FIRST_VALUE = "a12104c6134e57914f104f2521ba4422c4d7b184f4815541f80484e1e24161d64d54ba2210194510164d4f3a0534304e43e1e1da524612171b11701be45431cc1d16a52d11744e1961a114de55174f84e54371";
    private static final String SECOND_VALUE = "32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee11d945cd7fc81a05e9f85aac650e9052ba6a8cd8257bf14d13e6f0a803b54fde9e77472dbff89d71b57bddef121336cb85ccb8f3315f4b52e301d16e9f52f904";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger firstValueToXor = new BigInteger(FIRST_VALUE, VALUES_RADIX);
        BigInteger secondValueToXor = new BigInteger(SECOND_VALUE, VALUES_RADIX);
        BigInteger result = firstValueToXor.xor(secondValueToXor);
        String stringResultRepresentation = result.toString(VALUES_RADIX);
        System.out.println(stringResultRepresentation);

        try {
            byte[] asciiResultRepresentation = stringResultRepresentation.getBytes("US-ASCII");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asciiResultRepresentation));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i convert the output to ASCII?